# How can I group a twig array by value?

Tags: foreach, twig

This is my twig code:

```
{% for page in output.pages %}
<li>{{page.name}}</li> <li>{{page.menu}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The output is

```
green colors
blue colors
yellow colors
orange colors
magenta colors
frog animals
elephant animals
```

I try to group this into the menu elements. The result I would need is:

```
colors
   green
   blue
   yellow
   orange
   magenta
animals
   frog
   elephant
```

This is my approach:

```
    {% for page in output.pages %}
      {% for menu in page.menu %}
       <ul>{{menu}}</ul>
        <li>{{page.name}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But it is not grouping the pages by menu.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Twig for this? Why not write a custom Twig function that handles this stuff? This could be testable and would not need that much logic in the templating(!) language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
{% set ul = '' %}
{% for page in pages|sort((a, b) => a.menu <=> b.menu) %}
    {% if ul == '' %} <ul> {% endif %}
    {% if ul != page.menu %} 
        {% if ul != '' %} </ul></li> {% endif %}
        {% set ul = page.menu %} 
        <li>{{ page.menu }}<ul>
    {% endif %}
    <li>{{page.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
{% if ul != '' %} </ul></li></ul> {% endif %}
```

See [twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/99ctsy)